# Using file_get_contents to download a portion of data?

Tags: php

Is it possible to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to download a portion of data. For example, if I'm downloading a text file that is 2MB, and I only want the first 5 bytes, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The additional arguments allow you to specify a portion of the file. See example #3 on the manual page:

```
<?php
// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
var_dump($section);
?>
```

Here, the last two arguments limit the amount of data returned to just the portion of interest.

**Note:** The *offset* argument is a little unpredictable with remote files, as stated also on the manual page:

> Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files. Attempting to seek on non-local files may work with small offsets, but this is unpredictable because it works on the buffered stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ranger($url, $bytes){
    $headers = array(
    "Range: bytes=0-".$bytes
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

$url = "http://example.com/textfile.txt";

$raw = ranger($url, 5);

echo $raw;
```

Keep in mind that Range header must be supported by server. With fgc I think it is impossibru, even if it is, you should use cURL.

Comment: But, if the server does not support Range than why use cURL if it's going to cause the whole file to download? Whereas fgc allows an offset. Don't get me wrong, I use cURL and was aware of range, but I can't be 100% the servers I am connecting to support it.

Comment: @GV1, but if cURL can't do it without Range, how can file_get_contents on remote file? It will be downloaded completely.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't file_get_contents only download the the amount of data specified with the offset? Or does it download the complete file and return the offset?

Comment: I think they will behave the same.